# Detect inAppBrowser in reactJs application

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I don't want to open my react app in inAppbrowsers. I have searched but did not find anything.
For eg., I don't want to open my React website in facebook inappbrowser while  i post website link on facebook.
I have a Facebook Page and I have a website based on React. I share links on the Facebook page, and when I used the Facebook app on my mobile, the links open in Facebook in-app browser but i want to redirect to default browser of mobile app
Suggest any solutions.

Comment: Can you help us understand more of the context? How did you scaffold the app? What is `inAppBrowser`? Are you building a mobile app? I saw some hits related to Cordova.

Comment: i am creating react website and i don't want to open that website in inappbrowsers

Comment: The best solution would be to search for user-agents of in-app browsers, create a list of them and when you receive a request on server(since you are using next.js so its best to get the user-agent from request, check in the list of user-agents and redirect the user to a error/info page if it exists in that list.